# Edge Function middleware is referencing unsupported modules

Tags: next.js, vercel, storybook, clerk, edge-runtime

Im trying to deploy a storybook on vercel and get the following message error:

[image]

the project uses pnpm as package manager. Ive upgraded the last version of NextJs and Clerk, as well as downgrade NextJs, but the build is still crashing.

I found this thread [unsupported modules](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/45384), I tried all the paths discussed there, but I'm still having the same issue.

This is my middleware.ts file:

```js
import { authMiddleware } from '@clerk/nextjs';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export default authMiddleware({
  //@ts-ignore
  afterAuth(auth, req: NextRequest, evt: NextFetchEvent) {
    // handle users who aren't authenticated
    if (!auth.userId && !auth.isPublicRoute) {
      const signInUrl = new URL('/sign-in', req.url);
      // signInUrl.searchParams.set('redirect_url', req.url);
      return NextResponse.redirect(signInUrl);
    }
  },
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
};
```

I played with framework presets at vercel too.

[image]

I changed NextJs to Storybook, but no luck :(

[image]

I hope sb can provide a workaround or nice solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade nextjs version to 13.4.3

I had similar error about unsupported modules in middeleware.ts file. Downgrading the nextjs version worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact issue, and it seems to be solved now. I first tried to deploy it as a non-framework static web app with custom build commands. But by removing all of the  custom commands, and setting the framework to "Storybook" instead of "Other", everything worked out of the box without any custom setup etc!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and found something in [GitHub](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/45384)

Go to your Project Settings > Build & Development Settings, change the framework presets from Others to Next.js, and do a new deployment to work!